# Writing lambda in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, function

I am trying to convert this code into MATLAB but I am not sure how to do the subscripts (`Y[i] = Y[i-1]`) as well as the `func` and `f_exact` variables
heres the code:

```
def Forward_Euler(y0,t0,T,dt,f):
    t = np.arange(t0,T+dt,dt)
    Y = np.zeros(len(t))
    Y[0] = y0
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        Y[i] = Y[i-1]+dt*f(Y[i-1], t[i-1])
    return Y, t
    
func = lambda y,t: y-t
f_exact = lambda t: t+1-1/2*np.exp(t)
```

Comment: lambda function in MATLAB: `func = @(y,t) y - t`

Comment: Thanks you and for subscripts do I use Y{i} = Y{i-1}? @Reza

Comment: you need to use parenthesis `Y(i) = Y(i-1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) in matlab:

```matlab
func = @(y,t)(y - t)
f_exact = @(t)(t + 1 - exp(t)/2) % it works with any matrix t as well
```

And you can use for matrices as well (they should keep matrix operation rules). For example, in `func` function, as there is a minus in the form of function, the dimension of `y` and `t` must be the same.